# What's the difference between Databinder.Eval and Container.DataItem?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

When you're using asp.net databinding expressions:

```
<asp:Label Text='EXPRESSION' runat="server" />
```

What's the difference among:

```
Container.DataItem("Property")
```

and

```
Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Property")
```

and

```
Eval("Property")
```

and

```
Bind("Property")
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Eval` is one-way binding and `Bind` is for two way binding. Using `Eval` allows you to get the content into your page, but ASP.Net will not be able to put it back into an object for you.

The `Eval` method is just shorthand for `DataBinder.Eval`. Also, `Container.DataItem("Property")` is effectively the same as the `Eval` method except for when you want to return the value of a "path". For instance you can call `Eval` with a dot-separated "path" to a public property that you want the value of, but I do not believe you can do this with `Container.DataItem("Property")`.