# How to call a function in a repeater in the aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my aspx file I am trying to call a function.
I am getting an error (underlined red line) stating that there are some invalid arguments.

This is what I have:

```
public string TestFunction(string s)
{
    string v = s.Replace("&", "&amp;");
    return v;
}
```

My Type:

```
<%# TestFunction(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.UserName").ToString)%>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `s.Replace("&", "&amp;")` is what is underlined?

Comment: Should be ToString() (note the parenthesis)

Answer (score 5):

`<%# TestFunction(Eval("UserName").ToString())   %>` should do the trick.

Comment: Mike thanks that worked and I managed to keep the databinder/container in there as well. Could you explain how eval on its own is different to using this databinder/container statement? Just wondering if I am using things that I dont need. All data is coming from sp's and bound via code.

Comment: @user65697 check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1178863/1015495), it's already been covered better than I could explain it.

Comment: Thanks - I just read that it's better not to put these statements in the markup...this was old style apparently so perhaps I will format it in the code page and apply it before the databind.

Answer (score 1):

Change ToString to ToString() and it should be OK