# Why use Container.Dataitem in the scenario instead of Eval?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to data bind an array list to a repeater control. When I tried using Eval, it did not work. When I used Container.Dataitem, it works. Why the difference? In which cases should I use Eval and which cases should I use Container.Dataitem?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim values As New ArrayList()

    values.Add("Foo1")
    values.Add("Foo2")
    values.Add("Foo3")
    values.Add("Foo4")
    values.Add("Foo5")

    Repeater1.DataSource = values
    Repeater1.DataBind()
End Sub

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Container.DataItem %>
        </ItemTemplate>     
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Code, please? We're not mind readers.

Comment: Find out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178863/whats-the-difference-between-databinder-eval-and-container-dataitem

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sorry. I added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific case, `Eval` will not work because your `DataItem` objects are just plain strings.

The [documentation for the `Eval` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> The value of the expression parameter must evaluate to a public property.

Since `string` has no public property for getting its value, the `Eval` method will fail whereas the `Container.DataItem` property will be the actual string, so the value will be displayed.